# I can't deploy my nodejs application with cPanel

Tags: node.js, web, frontend, backend, cpanel

my web application is created by node.js javascript and html css, it contains two folders; server folder which contains bakend files, and another client folder which contains frontend files. I tried to deploy the application on my subdomain (Reebot) which is created for a previously hosted domain name (reebot.trainingteach.com). both backend and frontend folders contain package.json files, both must be running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnU86.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfQf7.png)

all steps are done but still error 503. Is there a precise method to deploy this application I lost all my thoughts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.